# JavaScript DOM traverse

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get all childs from `<article class="birds">`, but cant reach these ones that are in `<li class="bird">Hawk` ... I am trying to do it with recursion.

```
function traverse (node){
    node = document.getElementsByClassName(node)[0];
    for(let i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++){
        let child = node.childNodes[i];
        if(child.nodeName == '#text'){
            continue;
        }else{
            console.log(child.nodeName.toLowerCase() + 
                        ": class=\"" + child.className +"\"");
            if(child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE){
                traverse(child.className);
            }
        }

    }
}
traverse('birds');

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Living Creatures</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <article class="birds">
            <h2 class="birds-heading">Birds</h2>
            <ul class="birds-list">
                <li class="bird">Nightingale</li>
                <li class="bird">Owl</li>
                <li class="bird">Hawk
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-bird">Black Hawk</li>
                        <li class="sub-bird">Chicago Hawk</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="eagle" class="bird">Eagle</li>
                <li class="bird">Sparrow</li>
                <li class="bird">Falcon</li>
                <li class="bird">Blackbird</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
        <article class="mammals">
            <h2 class="mammal-heading">Mammals</h2>
            <ol class="mammal-list">
                <li id="dolphin" class="mammal">Dolphin</li>
                <li class="mammal">Elephant</li>
                <li class="mammal">Hyena</li>
            </ol>
        </article>

    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it because `<ul>` element does not have a class attr?  The ouput i get is :

```
h2: class="birds-heading"
ul: class="birds-list"
li: class="bird"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get to the `li` with class `birds-list` since the parent `ul` does not have a `class` and your traverse code is dependant on a `class`.

Instead, you can tweak the code to traverse by `node`. I have made the change to your code and it works.

```
function traverse (node){
    for(let i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++){
        let child = node.childNodes[i];
        if(child.nodeName == '#text'){
            continue;
        }else{
            console.log(child.nodeName.toLowerCase() + 
                        ": class=\"" + child.className +"\"");
            if(child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE){
                traverse(child);
            }
        }

    }
}
traverse(document.getElementsByClassName('birds')[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Per my understanding, you are trying to fetch all `li`s from container `.birds`. If yes, you can just use `querySelectorAll` instead of manually traversing DOM and searching manually.

```js
function traverse(className, fetchElement){
  return document.querySelectorAll("."+className +" " + fetchElement)
}

console.log(traverse('birds', 'li'))
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="birds">
    <h2 class="birds-heading">Birds</h2>
    <ul class="birds-list">
      <li class="bird">Nightingale</li>
      <li class="bird">Owl</li>
      <li class="bird">Hawk
        <ul>
          <li class="sub-bird">Black Hawk</li>
          <li class="sub-bird">Chicago Hawk</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="eagle" class="bird">Eagle</li>
      <li class="bird">Sparrow</li>
      <li class="bird">Falcon</li>
      <li class="bird">Blackbird</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <article class="mammals">
    <h2 class="mammal-heading">Mammals</h2>
    <ol class="mammal-list">
      <li id="dolphin" class="mammal">Dolphin</li>
      <li class="mammal">Elephant</li>
      <li class="mammal">Hyena</li>
    </ol>
  </article>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I`m trying to walk through each element, but your method is something a didn`t know! Thank you very much!